# XML File reading string failed

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I'm trying to read from XML file.
I success to read an int. but when I want to convert it so string it doesn't works. I would like to get some help.

XML:

```
<Data>
    <ServerClient>1</ServerClient>
    <ClientIP>127.0.0.1</ClientIP>
    <ClientPort>11000</ClientPort>
</Data>
```

The function getType reads good the int in the XML file.

```
private XmlDocument doc;

public int getType()
{
    try
    {
        // Open the file again
        doc.Load("ServerClientXML.xml");

        // Read port
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Data/ServerClient");

        return int.Parse(node.InnerText); // 0 = Server, 1 = Client
    }
    catch
    {
        return -1; 
    }
}

public string getIP()
{
    string ip;
    XmlNode node;

    try
    {
        // Open the file again
        doc.Load("ServerClientXML.xml");

        int Type = getType();
        if (Type == 1) // Client type
        {
            // Read IP
            node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Data/ServerClient/ClientIP");
            ip = doc.InnerXml;

        }
        else // Server Type
        {
            // Read IP
            node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Data/ServerClient/ServerIP");
            ip = doc.InnerXml;
        }

        return ip;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have tried to to like getType but without any success :

```
 return node.InnerText.toString(); // 0 = Server, 1 = Client
```

Comment: XPath you show in second function don't match your XML sample.

Comment: Don't do this: `catch { return something }` because you won't know whether your routine succeeded or not. Exceptions would tell you what was wrong if you didn't throw them away.

Comment: You also left off the part where you instantiate `doc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath doesn't match provided XML. It should be `/Data/ClientIP` and `/Data/ServerIP`

Comment: Problem already solved by my check, after 12 hours on computer I lose my focus. Thank's any way. :)